# How to use Laravel's attach() on filtered query result?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to use `attach()` on a filtered Builder result:

```
$users = User::whereIn('type', array(1, 2))->get();

$usersType_1 = $users->filter(function($item) {
    return $item->type == 1;
});

$usersType_2 = $users->filter(function($item) {
    return $item->type == 2;
});

$usersType_1->role()->attach(3);
$usersType_2->role()->attach(4);
```

So, I need to attach the `role` based on the user `type`. The `role()` method is specified on the `User` model

The `attach()` part from the code above throws the following error: **Method role() doesn't exist** - which I assume happens because `filter()` returns a Collection.

Is there a working way to attach pivot entries on filtered Builder result? Or do I need to run 2 separate queries and run `attach()` on them respectively?

Comment: roles () function not exists are you extracting that model into the controller

Comment: All happens in another model. The `role()` method is specified on the `User` model.

Comment: role function is there in User Model.

Comment: You couldn't use `role` method no collection instead of `User` model?

Comment: @mrabbani Thing is, I store the Builder result in the `$users` variable, but when I `filter` the result, the filtered "parts" are no longer Builder objects, hence they don't have access to the `role()` relationship. I'm wondering if there's a way to filter the result *and* get Builder objects back, instead of Collection.

Comment: Use chain `all()` method after `filter`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
$usersType_1 = $users->where('type', 1); // or whereType(1)
$usersType_1->role()->attach(3);

$usersType_2 = $users->where('type', 2); // or whereType(1)
$usersType_2->role()->attach(4);
```

I think the "Method role() doesn't exist" exception occurs because you're filtering an *Eloquent Collection*.

EDIT: I see why this doesn't work. It's because you're trying to attach an entire collection to a role. It would work if you used find() and then attached a role.

So you should loop over all the users with type 1 and attach the role

```
foreach ($usersType_1 as $user) {
   $user->role()->attach(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use `role` method no collection instead of `User` model. Try by:

```
$users = User::whereIn('type', array(1, 2))->get();

$usersType_1 = $users->filter(function($item) {
   if($item->type == 1) {

       return $item->role()->attach(3);
   }
})
->all();

$usersType_2 = $users->filter(function($item) {
    if($item->type == 2) {

        return $item->role()->attach(4);
    }
})
->all();
```

Alternative :

```
$users = User::whereIn('type', array(1, 2))->get();

$usersType_1 = $users->filter(function($item) {
  $item->type == 1;
})
->all();

$usersType_2 = $users->filter(function($item) {
   return $item->type == 2;
})
->all();

$role1 = Role::find(3);
$role2 = Role::find(4);

$role1->users()->attach($usersType_1->puck('id'));

$role2->users()->attach($usersType_2->puck('id'));
```

Comment: Won't this basically act as a loop, in which `attach()` will be used `N` times? If yes, it won't be very efficient assuming I have lots of users of both types.

Comment: Alternatives is assign `users` to `role`. First find `Role` attach `users`.